# I need to apply update and delete in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dbcontext, edmx

Basically i have created a mvc application that will be performing CRUD operations on the database data using entity framework generated from database edmx.So in this after adding EDM and configuring database settings i've added a controller named CRUD with scaffolding enabled to read/write action views and attached model and DB conttext to it.Now everything works as desired upto the point of adding new employee ie Create.The problem comes when i run the index page of crud controller and in which when i press the actionlink edit or delete for any specific employee data it doesn't find that Edit and Delete cshtml pages at all and instead shows the error 404 resource not found.Please help me figure out what's wrong,i'm posting my whole code below:

```
public class CRUDController : Controller
{
    private TestDBEntities2 db = new TestDBEntities2();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Emps.ToList());
    }
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Emp emp = db.Emps.Find(id);
        if (emp == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Emp emp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Emps.Add(emp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Emp emp = db.Emps.Find(id);
        if (emp == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Emp emp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Emp emp = db.Emps.Find(id);
        if (emp == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Emp emp = db.Emps.Find(id);
        db.Emps.Remove(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Emp>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  /*id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication2.Emp
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Emp</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Edit.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication2.Emp
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Emp</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Image of Solution Explorer:
[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: why did you comment "id=item.PrimaryKey" in ActionLinks?

Comment: I don't think your action links are passing the correct params

Comment: you should pass "id=item.EmployeeID" in ActionLinks

Comment: @Ali7091 sir thank you so much!you should have placed that in answer directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass EmployeeID in your ActionLinks:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id=item.EmployeeID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id=item.EmployeeID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id=item.EmployeeID })
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the Controller Name

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "CRUD", new {/*id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "CRUD", new { /*id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "CRUD", new { /*id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
```